# How to address an image which is in system resource in android

Tags: java, android, drawable, android-drawable

I am writing a media player in which I am using Image buttons and Images are from **system resource**. Now in java file, how should it be addressed?
here is the code:

```
case R.id.ib2:
    if (isPlaying) {
         pause();
         //the red line is under R.drawable.ic_media_pause
         playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
```

Comment: I need to provide an address for setImageResource()

Comment: Or finding system resource images and put them in drawable folder(how?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use android's resource file, like so:

```
playPause.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
```

Or You can add it to the imports if you aren't using ***any*** of your own resources:

```
import android.R;
```

Comment: Yes, not *your* `R`, but Android's. @Civiato

Comment: Is there any idea about how to find the original file?

Comment: for example, there isn't a ic_media_stop image. and have no idea how to arrange dimensions if i want to create it.

Comment: if i have the size of others, then i can easily make it.

Comment: ic_media_stop came about in 4.0 this site may be of use to you: http://androiddrawables.com/